# Why is iPad not able to render "offline" plotly plots but iPhone can?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, plotly

If I host an offline plotly plot on a website (for example, [on a github.io page here](https://blondegeek.github.io/plots/tetra_rot_tetra_tensor_product.html)), I'm able to view the plot on my desktop and my iPhone (iOS 12.0, Safari) but not on my iPad (iOS 12.1, Safari, and Chrome) -- I get a "WebGL is not supported by your browser" message.

However, for all these devices, the plots on a webpage such as [this one](https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-plots/) renders with no problems. What causes the difference in rendering offline plotly plots between my iPhone and iPad?

Comment: Adding exact versions of Safari and iDevices may help

Comment: iDevice versions: iPhone X (2018), iPad Pro (2018)

Comment: Safari version: matches iOS version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a weird case, I'm adding another answer to try to explain better what I think it is.

Python's plotly (aka plotly.py) uses plotly.js under the hood, when you download a plot as html it includes the library plotly.js in the html file (you can check it using the browser's development tools).

The `offline` module of the same plotly.py's version will always include the same plotly.js version, whereas `online` module probably includes the plotly.js currently being used by plotly's plot.ly platform, or at least That would explain the divergence between those modules. The examples on plotly's documentation seem to be rendered without even using plotly.js by checking the code using the browser's tools.

In addition, plotly.js is going through a rewriting process of its WebGL code as you can see in this [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/949) that was originally targeted for version 2 but might come in sooner, where you can see in a comment:

> Along with this transition - or perhaps even better before it - we
>   should find a way to test webgl plots in iOS - perhaps using
>   https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/api ? We need to make sure
>   that bugs we've fixed before - such as #280, #1868 (any others that
>   are iOS-specific?) - don't come back with this rewrite.

where you can see references to [issues](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/280) similar to this one.

**TL DR**: other than keep your browsers and plotlys up to date there's not much you can do about this, plotly's code is quite dynamic so you should check for updates every now and then.

Comment: I upgraded to plotly==3.4.2 (plotly.js 1.42.5). I was using a python binding version that was using 1.39.2 before. I’m still having the same issue but am continuing to look into the links you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers support WebGL, but sometimes it is disabled by default. I don't use safari but you can find small [guides](http://onvert.com/guides/enable-webgl-safari/) to enable it on the web, there are also other [sites](http://webglreport.com) where you can check if it is enabled and discard that issue. Not all of plotly's plots use WebGL although I think surface plots do, so you might want to check if it is enabled first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case, WebGL is definitely enabled on the iPad. As you mentioned, the 3D Surface plot I linked to on plotly's site requires WebGL (and renders on the iPad fine) and also if I go to get.webgl.org I get confirmation that the browser does support WebGL. It seems to be something specific about offline vs. online mode for plotly -- I was able to successfully view the same plot in online mode (aka through plotly's server).

Comment: I looked up the repo but couldn't find the code, as you mentioned online and offline modules, are you using plotly.py? what version? what are you using to display the plots in the front end?

Comment: Hi vlizana sorry for the confusion. When I say "online" versus "offline" I'm referring to plotly.plotly versus plotly.offline and I'm using the function iplot from either when I'm plotting in a notebook. Let me create a simple example.

Comment: Here’s a code gist that one can run in a jupyter notebook:
https://gist.github.com/blondegeek/b7eb7eec68829c362a12abf3833494dd

As explained in the comments, plotly.plotly.iplot works fine, but plotly.offline.iplot does not. This seems to also be the case for plots saved to html (if it was plotted with plotly.offline, the plot will not render and instead display “WebGL is not supported by your browser”). Hope that helps! Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of things I tried which worked.

1. If you are using google Colab, use this code-

   import plotly.io as pio

   pio.renderers.default = "colab"
2. Go to iPad settings —> Safari —> Advanced —> Experimental Features —>     Turn on Web GL 2.0